# Proposed "flagged as duplicate" was declined, then question was edited to propose same link

Tags: support, declined-flags

I do not have much track of flag history, except that I checked there now. I see that it has become "decline" on a flag of "exact duplicate" but the question are closed and moderated into the same link, which is proposed in the flag. Did I miss something?

The current post is here; 
[IS there any open source Web based IDE for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868261/is-there-any-open-source-web-based-ide-for-net)

It was last active 2011-05-03 11:55. My flag was created 2011-05-03 10:57, 16 minutes after OP created the question. But I also see the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5868261/revisions) now and found Community (Oct 3 -11 at 16:45) insert duplicate link

Comment: Was this an old flag that was cast before it was eventually closed or fairly recent? If it was recent, the decision has already been made and isn't helpful at all.

Comment: That would be a reason but I can't see why I would flag an already deemed question. I looked at the activity now. It was last active 2011-05-03 11:55. My flag was created 2011-05-03 10:57, 16 minutes after op created the question. But I also see the edits now and found `Community (Oct 3 -11 at 16:45) insert duplicate link`,

Comment: Its a year ago that this happened, and almost half a year between your flag and the accepted flag.  These are judgement calls, and therefore may be decided one way or another on close calls.  The basic question, "why are people not deterministic" has been asked a hundred times already.

Comment: @Won't. It looks like a unexpected behavior to me, likely repeated elsewhere. That's why I maked it a question here. I don't take time and/or care about the flag itself.